# Scroll items at different speeds as page scrolls

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a page with three rows of thumbnail images. Each image is the same width, but the heights vary, so when scrolling the page, the rows all end at different times. I am looking for a way to have each row scroll at a different speed, so that they all end together at the bottom of the page. Sort of like a vertical parallax effect. Is this even possible?

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="thumbnails">
  <ul id="row-one">
    <li class="thumb1">...</li>
    <li class="thumb2">...</li>
  </ul>  
  <ul id="row-two">
    <li class="thumb1">...</li>
    <li class="thumb2">...</li>
    <li class="thumb3">...</li>
    <li class="thumb4">...</li>
  </ul>  
  <ul id="row-three">
    <li class="thumb1">...</li>
    <li class="thumb2">...</li>
    <li class="thumb3">...</li>
  </ul>
```

and my css:

```
#thumbnails { width: 100%; }
ul { float: left; display: inline; width: 33%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery .scroll function. View documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/).

When scroll is triggered move the targets at different speeds.

Do what you would've done on parallax scrolling but vertical, there are plenty of tutorials as you probably allready know.

Hope this was of any help.